# Is it possible to use Django-Admin editor/interface outside of the admin?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that I need to edit. I have it registered in Admin.py. It works fine in my admin. How do I use this particular editing interface in other parts of my project? What I mean is, I want to use the admin editor on another template to do exactly what the admin does inside of it. Is there a module or library that will let me do this in django?

Comment: Do you mean [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/)? Or you want same interface?

Comment: No no, I don't mean django forms. I mean, the django-admin interface. I want the same thing inside my app. I don't want to build a new admin, I just want to use everything it has, but in a different place.

Comment: Do you want to change its access url `/admin`?

Comment: Nope, I'm looking at a way to import whatever the admin does into my app for editing models without actually having to write all of that again. Basically I want my app's edit feature to have everything the admin has